# Fragments with setRetainInstance(true) during orientation changes

Tags: android, android-fragments

What is the lifecycle of fragments during the orientation change when they are set to retainInstance? What functions are called and what are not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During orientation change, onCreateView() and onActivityCreated() functions are called again. But bundle is not given since the fragment is only detached and not destroyed. This means that all the variables of the fragments should be set during onCreate itself and not in onActivityCreated. Also, onActivityCreated() can directly access the variables not using them from the savedInstanceState.